# select/deselect all check boxes on click a single check box by javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a form in which I have two table with some rows .
[image]

I want that when I click on *select/unselect all* check box than checkboxes under the that check box should checked for that particular table

I have a javascript function that works but when I click any of two *select/unselect all checkbox* than both tables checkboxes are checked.
I want to check all checkboxes for the particular table only.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
checked=false;
function checkedAll (frm1) {
    var aa= document.getElementById('frm1');
     if (checked == false)
          {
           checked = true
          }
        else
          {
          checked = false
          }
    for (var i =0; i < aa.elements.length; i++) 
    {
     aa.elements[i].checked = checked;
    }
      }

      //function for subscription month


</script>
```

my html is....

```
<form action="" method="post" name="frm1" id="frm1">

<table>
<tr><th>Cause List</th></tr>
<?php 
foreach($arr as $month)
{
?>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="causelist_month" /><?php echo $month; ?></td></tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr><th><input type="checkbox" name="causelist_month" id="causelist_month" onclick="checkedAll (frm1);"/>select all/unselect all</th></tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr><th>Subscription</th></tr>
<?php 
foreach($arr as $month)
{
?>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month"/><?php echo $month; ?></td></tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr><th><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month" id="subscription_month" onclick="checkedAll2 (frm2);"/>select all/unselect all</th></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

please help me.

Comment: What if you change `aa.elements[i].checked = checked` with `aa.elements[i].checked = true` ?

Comment: <form action="" method="post" name="frm1" id="frm1">

Comment: <form action="" method="post" name="frm1" id="frm1">
<table><tr><th>Cause List</th></tr>
<?php 
foreach($arr as $month)
{
?>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="causelist_month" /><?php echo $month; ?></td></tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr><th><input type="checkbox" name="causelist_month" id="causelist_month" onclick="checkedAll (frm1);"/>select all/unselect all</th></tr>
</table>

Comment: It looks like you only have one form. Why is the second table not inside `frm2`?

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery 1.6+, you can do

```
$('.check-all').click(function () {
    var checked = this.prop('checked');   
    this.closest('table').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
}
```

where `check-all` is a class that the two **"select/unselect all"** checkboxes have.

Comment: OP didn't tag the question with jQuery. From the JavaScript tag description: *"Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."*

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your code. The most important one is that you are a a single *checked* variable to keep track of the state for *both* forms. That cannot work. Instead, use the status of the "checkall" checkbox for the other checkboxes.

Lets assume you really have two forms (if you cannot use two forms, see below):

```
<form action="" method="post" name="frm1" id="frm1">
    <table>    
        <tr><th>Cause List</th></tr>
        <!-- ... -->
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" name="causelist_month" id="causelist_month" onclick="checkedAll.call(this);"/>select all/unselect all
            </th>
        </tr>  
    </table>
</form>

<form action="" method="post" name="frm2" id="frm2">
    <table>    
        <tr><th>Subscription List</th></tr>
        <!-- ... -->
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month" id="subscription_month" onclick="checkedAll.call(this);"/>select all/unselect all
            </th>
        </tr>  
    </table>
</form>
```

Note that I changed the inline event handler to `checkedAll.call(this)`.

Then your function should look like this:

```
function checkedAll() {
    // this refers to the clicked checkbox
    // find all checkboxes inside the checkbox' form
    var elements = this.form.getElementsByTagName('input');
    // iterate and change status
    for (var i = elements.length; i--; ) {
        if (elements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
            elements[i].checked = this.checked;
        }
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gx8p2/)

Of course there are ways to improve the code. For example you probably want to add the logic to deselect the respective "select all" checkbox when any if the other checkboxes in the table is deselected.

I also recommend to read the great [introduction to event handling on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html), to learn about other ways of binding event handlers.

---

If you cannot use two forms, you have to find another ancestor as reference point (i.e. from which you select all the checkboxes). In this case, the `table` element seems preferable. You have to traverse up the document, until you find it.
The inline click event handler still has to be changed to `checkedAll.call(this)` for this to work:

```
function checkedAll() {
    // this refers to the clicked checkbox

    // find closest table
    var parent = this.parentNode;
    do {
        parent = parent.parentNode;
    } while(parent.nodeName !== 'TABLE');

    // find all checkboxes inside the checkbox' table
    var elements = parent.getElementsByTagName('input');

    // ... continue like shown above
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is changing all checkbox which are inside `frm1`. Keep two tables inside two separate div's and pass corresponding divs id to `checkedAll` function .

```
<form action="" method="post" name="frm1" id="frm1"> 
<div id="div1">
<table>  
   <tr>
         <th>Cause List</th>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach($arr as $month) { ?> 
   <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="causelist_month" />
   <?php echo $month; ?></td></tr> 
   <?php } ?> 
   <tr>
   <th>
    <input type="checkbox" name="causelist_month" id="causelist_month" onclick="checkedAll (div1);"/>select all/unselect all</th></tr> </table>  
   </div>
   <div id="div2">
   // Second table
   </div>  
  </form>
```

Comment: For this to work, the event handler would have to be changed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this --

```
$(input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

HTML -

```
<div><label><input id="ChkAll" type="checkbox" onchange="javascript:CheckedAll();" /><span>SelectAll</span></label></div> 
 <div id="DivChk ">
    <label><input type="checkbox" /><span>First</span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /><span>2nd</span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /><span>3rd</span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /><span>4th</span></label>
</div>
```

My Jquery -

```
function CheckedAll(){
     if ($('#ChkAll').is(':checked')) {
          $('#DivChk input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', 'checked');           
     }
     else {
          $('#DivChk input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeAttr('checked');
     }
   }
```

[Try This using Jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/2c2ws/)

BY Javascript -

```
function CheckedAll(){    
     if (document.getElementById('ChkAll').checked) {
         for(i=0; i<document.getElementsByTagName('input').length;i++){
         document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].checked = true;
         }
     }
     else {
         for(i=0; i<document.getElementsByTagName('input').length;i++){
          document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].checked = false;
         }
     }
   }
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/GbZMT/1/)

Comment: OP didn't tag the question with jQuery. From the JavaScript tag description: *"Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."*

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('input')` will get *all* checkboxes, not only the one of the respective table. Besides, calling `getElementsByTagName` that often is quite inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function checkedAll(frm1) {
  var chk = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for(var i=0; i < chk.length; i++) {
    if(chk[i].type == 'checkbox') {
      chk[i].checked = frm1.checked;
    }
  }
}
```

or you can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251005/javascript-select-all-checkboxes-in-a-table).

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('input')` will find *all* `input` elements on the whole page!

Comment: In pure javascript there isn't any way to find the checkbox directly. after getting input field need to check it's type as "checkbox" i.e. if(chk[i].type == 'checkbox').

Comment: That's not what I meant. You are iterating over all checkboxes of the page, while the OP only wants to iterate the boxes of the respective table.

Comment: I understand; here I put the logic which OP can follow. I think he will able to get an idea from this :)

Answer (score 0):

try this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/TYpjQ/1/)**

```
var checked=false;
function checkedAll () {
var aa =  document.getElementsByName("causelist_month");
checked = document.getElementById('causelist_month').checked;

for (var i =0; i < aa.length; i++) 
{
    aa[i].checked = checked;
}
}

function checkedAll2() {
var aa =  document.getElementsByName("subscription_month");
checked = document.getElementById('subscription_month').checked;


for (var i =0; i < aa.length; i++) 
{
    aa[i].checked = checked;
}
}
```

Comment: I think you should remove the `if (checked == true){...} else {...}` statement. Setting `checked` to `true` if it is `true` seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: @FelixKling, `if()` condition removed Thanks :)