# Javascript: How to get selected checkbox items in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a checkbox, where I am loading its inputs from a web service. I'm developing a function which filters the selected items and puts them in a table.

My checkbox looks like this:

```
<label class="checkbox" data-match-for="filtre-competences">
    <input id="checkbox_competence" name="missionPlace" value="" type="checkbox" data-match-forcontent="id-competence">
    <span class="check"></span>
    <span class="checkbox-title" data-match-forcontent="titre-competence"></span>
    <span>(<span data-match-forcontent="nb-mission"></span>)</span>
</label>
```

I want to filter the selected elements in a table and of course deselect items which may bed deselected dynamically.

My function looks like this:

```
selectCompetences:function () {
    var checkbox = document.querySelector('#checkbox_competence');
    var arr = new Array();
    checkbox.addEventListener('click',function () {
        if () {
            //selected : add to table
            arr.push(checkbox.getAttribute("value"))
        }
        else {
            // deselected: remove from table
        }
    })
}
```

I need to complete this function. Any suggestions?

Comment: What if `value` is not unique ? How will you remove it ? You need to change your approach..

Comment: you want, `this.checked`??

Comment: yeah i wanna recyuper which are selected or deselected in each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   var values = new Array();

  $.each($("input[name='case[]']:checked").closest("td").siblings("td"),
   function () {
        values.push($(this).text());
   });

  alert("val---" + values.join(", "));
```

Comment: Hi Samudrala - your code-only answer would be better with some context. For example, you could explain how this is a solution to the questioner's original problem; that would also make it more useful to other readers looking for answers to similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function togglecheckboxes(master,group){
    var cbarray = document.getElementsByName(group);
    for(var i = 0; i < cbarray.length; i++){
        cbarray[i].checked = master.checked;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbgroup1_master" onchange="togglecheckboxes(this,'cbg1[]')"> Toggle All
<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1_1" class="cbgroup1" name="cbg1[]" value="1"> Item 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1_2" class="cbgroup1" name="cbg1[]" value="2"> Item 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1_3" class="cbgroup1" name="cbg1[]" value="3"> Item 3<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1_4" class="cbgroup1" name="cbg1[]" value="4"> Item 4<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if want more for reference check this link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802498/select-deselect-all-check-boxes-on-click-a-single-check-box-by-javascript